# Чудеса с input через переменную и без

Tags: javascript, input, переменные

Пишу интерактивную страничку бинарного поиска, где пользователь сам вводит значения границ массива, искомого значения и т.д.
Нахожусь на стадии валидации поля искомого числа, чтобы оно не вываливалось за пределы массива. Логика проста, если число больше или меньше границ массива - выводится алерт с ошибкой и значение инпута сбрасывается до значения по умолчанию:

```
let num = document.querySelector('.main__input-number').value

if (num > max || num < min) {
    alert('Wrong number!\nCheck if it is included in the array interval and try again.');
    num = 1;
}
```

В таком случае, сброс значения инпута до единицы происходить не будет (непонятно почему), но если отказаться от переменной **num**, просто использовать селектор, то сброс происходит:

```
let num = document.querySelector('.main__input-number').value

if (num > max || num < min) {
    alert('Wrong number!\nCheck if it is included in the array interval and try again.');
    document.querySelector('.main__input-number').value = 1;
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, объяснив почему инпут не хочет принимать значение через переменную, ведь так код смотрится красивее и отказываться от такого способа не хочется. Заранее спасибо

Comment: `.value` - строка, что чревато множеством ошибок.

Comment: В первом варианте вы меняете локальную переменную. Внешний мир (`DOM`) об этом ничего не знает. Во втором варианте вы меняете `DOM` и пользователь видит это изменение.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, тип у инпута стоит "number", ошибок вроде не должно быть, если невозможно в импут ввести НЕчисло

Comment: Не вижу никаких чудес, все, вроде, логично...вы сбрасываете именно значение input-а, к нему и стоит обращаться...

Comment: Тип инпута не влияет на представление значения в программе. Это строка.

Comment: Как насчет `let num_node = document.querySelector('.main__input-number');`, `parseInt(num_node.value)`  и `num_node.value = '1';`?

Comment: @Alexey, да, Вы правы, я ведь действительно перезаписываю содержимое num... 

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, Да, спасибо, как написали в ответе буду использовать переменную и при изменении обращаться через `.value`. Спасибо!

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, **"Тип инпута не влияет на представление значения в программе. Это строка."**
Подскажите для незнающего, правильнее поставить type="text" и делать валидацию на число через js или оставить type="number" и не париться? На реальных проектах пользователя не будет смущать стрелочки вверх-вниз у импута?

Comment: `.value` внутри программы будет строкой для любого типа инпута. Тип инпута влияет только на UI.

Comment: @Александр, подскажу, что у `input` значение можно получить не только через `value`, а еще через `valueAsNumber`. На выходе будет именно тип данных `number`. Вообще я вам советую попробовать `TypeScript`, он очень поможет найти банальные ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так невозможно сделать, потому что сам язык это не позволяет.

Но есть обходной путь: создать функцию, а потом вызывать её:

```js
let input = document.querySelector('.main__input-number')

function changeValue(value) {
    input.value = value;
}

if (+input.value > max || +input.value < min) {
    alert('Wrong number!\nCheck if it is included in the array interval and try again.');
    // 1 - значение, которое вам нужно
    changeValue(1);
}
```

Либо, можно вообще сделать так:

```js
let input = document.querySelector('.main__input-number')

if (+input.value > max || +input.value < min) {
    alert('Wrong number!\nCheck if it is included in the array interval and try again.');
    // 1 - значение, которое вам нужно
    input.value = 1;
}
```

Как видите, всё просто и никаких "чудес" нет.

Comment: Зачем функция? Она не нужна.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Это как вариант.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Исправил.